# Madh'hab view from famous muhadditheens

Tags: source-identification, history, madhhab

I heard that famous scholars like Imam Bhukhari[rah], Imam Muslim[rah] were born after the period of Imams of Maddhabs(Abuhanifa[rah],Shafi[rah]).

So,they should heard about Fiqh(Maddhab) and they should mention something about that in their books or to their students.

What did they(Imam Bhukhari[rah], Imam Muslim[rah]) say about the Madhhabs?

Comment: the question is too broad and required research

Comment: One could say they had their own madhab (he was a kind of Mujtahid) at least for al-Bukhari this seems to fit as he wrote many "papers"! While Imam Muslim followed the madhab of ahl al-Hadith see also (in Arabic http://islamqa.info/ar/225816

Comment: Well i guess one part which makes your Question too broad is the Question *What did they(Imam Bhukhari[rah], Imam Muslim[rah]) say about the Madhhabs?* As they are two different people and might have different points of view! Because muhadditeens can't follow a madhab 100% just because they are obliged to the sunna they teaching first!